# How to hide View after a given time of inactivity

Tags: java, android, time, seekbar, android-seekbar

Basically I have a volume button that shows a hidden `SeekBar` when clicked, how to make the `SeekBar` go hidden again after 2 or 3 seconds of inactivity?

I just wanna know how can I check for how much time been spent since the `SeekBar` became visible without changing its progress!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a `Runnable` that sets the visibility of the `SeekBar` to invisible:

```
private final Runnable hideSeekBarRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
};
```

When the volume button is clicked, show the `SeekBar` and post the `Runnable` with a 2-3 sec delay:

```
seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
seekBar.postDelayed(hideSeekBarRunnable, 3000);
```

And if the `SeekBar` is interacted with (its progress changes), remove the pending `Runnable` and re-post it to reset the counter:

```
seekBar.removeCallbacks(hideSeekBarRunnable);
seekBar.postDelayed(hideSeekBarRunnable, 3000);
```